# show that $\int_0^1\frac{(dx)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{(1)}{(n)}*\beta({\frac{(1)}{(2)}},\frac{(1)}{(n)})$

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

Show that $\int_0^1\frac{(dx)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{(1)}{(n)}*\beta({\frac{(1)}{(2)}},\frac{(1)}{(n)})$ ,when $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

It was hard for me to prove it .

I integrated the left hand side and the result is $\frac{(\pi)}{(2)}$.

I thought that if I substitute the value of $n$ in the R.H.S I would get the same result as the L.H.S, but that didn't happen .

Is my thinking correct?
How can I solve it ?

Comment: $n=2$ works, so maybe you miscalculated that one.

Comment: When n is equal to 1, the value is not equal LHS and at n=3 the answer is approximately equal LHS .

Comment: Is there another way to help me to prove that L.H.S=R.H.S

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $x=\sin^{2/n}t$,$$\int_0^1x^{n/2-1}(1-x^n)^{1/n-1}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac2n\cos^{2/n-1}tdt=\frac1n\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,\,\frac1n\right).$$Your problem is the special case $n=2$. If you found $n=2$ didn't work, you've miscalculated $\left.\frac1n\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,\,\frac1n\right)\right|_{n=2}$.

Comment: When I found the result at n = 1, it was not equal to the left side , at n=2 i get the same result $\frac\{pi}{2}$which is the same value that I get when using any law that I have learned, as well as the way you wrote it.I want to show that the left side equals the right side when n is positive integer

Comment: @user94790 Maybe you misunderstood the question. Note s.t. is short for "such that". The statement "$A=B(n)$ s.t. $n\in\Bbb N$" means *there exists* an $n\in\Bbb N$ with $A=B(n)$, **not** *all* $n\in\Bbb N$ satisfy $A=B(n)$.

Comment: In the question that I have to solve ( ,n :positive integer)Do your words apply to these words?You have modified the question here.

Comment: @user94790 No I haven't, I just abbreviated "is a positive integer" as $\in\Bbb N$. Anyway, *you're* the one who's modified the question, in this case to take out the s.t.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to prove it at all n values? Or when n = 2 ??

Comment: @user94790 The question wanted you to *find* the $n$ that works. You can't prove it for all $n$, because it's then incorrect, as you already noted with the counterexample $n=1$.

Comment: I calculated the result for n at 1, 2, and 3 and finding the beta result was difficult at 3 and when I tried about 4 it was more difficult.  The value of the right side at n = 1 was equal to 2, and at n = 2 it was .... and at n = 3 it was approximately 1.7333 and here it was difficult to find a value manually (gamma 1/3) so I took it from the internet.I don't think I can find positive n values ​​that achieve the equation by substituting and finding a specific pattern? Can n values ​​be found in other ways? Or at n = 2 is the only value of n that satisfies the equation?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx=\left. \arcsin (x)\right\vert
_{0}^{1}=\frac{\pi }{2}
$$

How do you get the right side?

Comment: This link can be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Yes I thought if I substituted some values ​​for n the result would be

Comment: $\frac{(\pi)}{(2)}$. But the result was not equal to the n values ​​that i  substituted in  RHS

Comment: Sorry, I could not fully understand the problem.